# Using GNU Scientific Library (GSL) to draw a 2D B-Spline path using unevenly spaced points

Tags: c++, c, gsl, spline, bspline

I'm trying to using the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) to draw a smooth path from A to B. I'm using an API that returns a small number (8 in this case) of irregularly spaced points (in red), that you can see in the following picture:

[image: returned points and desired result from GSL]

The purple points represent the points that I would like to see returned from GSL.

Firstly, is this kind of 2D B-Spline shape obtainable by using GSL? I don't know much about B-Splines, let alone 2D B-Splines. I was able to get the B-Splines example shown [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-B_002dsplines.html#Example-programs-for-B_002dsplines) running and creating a smooth .ps file without problem, but that example uses uniform breakpoints with the following code:

```
/* use uniform breakpoints on [0, 15] */
gsl_bspline_knots_uniform(0.0, 15.0, bw);
```

In my case, given that the data I'm given is erratic and not evenly spaced, would I have to use non-uniform knots? I tried using `gsl_bspline_knots()`, in order to use non uniform breakpoints within the following test code, but I'm really not sure if this is the right direction or not.

```
#define NCOEFFS 8 // not sure what this number should be - number of data points?
#define NBREAK   (NCOEFFS - 2)
const size_t nbreak = NBREAK;

int main (void) {

    // (example code)...

    gsl_vector *non_uniform = gsl_vector_alloc(nbreak);

    // create some random breakpoint values
    for (i=0; i<nbreak; i++) {
        double val = gsl_ran_gaussian(r, 2.0);
        printf("val: %f\n", val);
        gsl_vector_set(non_uniform, i, val);
    }

    gsl_bspline_knots(non_uniform, bw);

    // (more example code)...
}
```

Further more, how would I translate the above example for drawing B-Splines in a 2D x/y coordinate space? If GNU Scientific Library is not suitable for this, could someone make a recommendation for a more suitable C/C++ library?

Any help or pointers in the direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First: **1D Basis splines**

Given a set of `NBREAK` breakpoints `(t_1, ..., t_{NBREAK})`, there are `NCOEFFS=NBREAK+2` cubic b-splines components `B_j(t)`. These functions and their first and second derivatives are always continuous, even at the breakpoints. Consequently, any fit given by the linear combination `f(t) = \sum m_j B_j(t)` will also share these properties (similar to natural cubic splines). The number of b-spline components, `NCOEFFS`, doesn't need to be equal to the number of data points, `NDATA`. If `NCOEFFS < NDATA`, you shall use least square minimization to get the fit (GSL documentation has a good example of minimum least square calculation to get a b-spline fit [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-B_002dsplines.html#Example-programs-for-B_002dsplines)). `NCOEFFS < NDATA` is good choice when the data contains noise  which does not seem to be your case

The reason why the number of coefficients is not equal to the number of breakpoints, `NCOEFFS=NBREAK+2`, is related to the fact that you don't specify a boundary condition when dealing with basis splines. Given that people usually are more familiar with natural cubic splines, it is worth commenting that [natural cubic splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) impose the boundary condition `d^2f(x)/dx^2=0`. That is why any representation of natural cubic splines using cubic polynomial basis would have `NCOEFFS=NBREAK`. [Here is a link](http://tardis.viniciusmiranda.com:7990/projects/WEB/repos/useful-public-documents/browse/lect_spline.pdf) to a very good explanation about the counting of the degrees of freedom given by the coefficients of the cubic polynomials that represent both natural the b-splines and the number of equations necessary to impose the continuity of `f(t)`, `df(t)/dt` and `d^2f(t)/dt^2`).

Finally: **Fit a parametric curve using b-splines**.

You have the set of "data" points `(x_1, y_1)....(x_{NDATA},y_{NDATA})` and you want to construct a parametric fit `P(t)=( f_1(t), f_2(t) )`. B-splines fit won't go through all the data points if `NCOEFFS<NDATA` (you can demand that if you choose your breakpoints carefully and `NCOEFFS=N_DATA`). In my research, I only work with 1D nonparametric fits (`y=f(x)`) but I believe this parametric case is similar. I would try the following

STEP 1: Create the set of "data" points `(t, x) = {(1, x_1), (2, x_2)...(NDATA, x_{NDATA})}` and use gsl 1D b-splines to fit them. This fit will give you `f_1(t) = sum_{i=1}^{NCOEFFS} mx_j B_j(t)` with `t \in [1,NDATA]`.

STEP 2: Now construct the set of "data" points `(t, y) = {(1, y_1), (2, y_2)...(NDATA, y_{NDATA})}` and use b-splines to fit them. This will provide you `f_2(t) = sum_{i=1}^{NCOEFFS} my_j B_j(t)` with `t \in [1,NDATA]`

Now plot `P(t)=( f_1(t), f_2(t) ), t \in [1,NDATA]`. Basically, I mapped a 2 D parametric curve problem in 2 1D nonparametric fits (which is what GSL provides).

The last point is the choice of breakpoints (and the number of basis components `NCOEFFS`) in step 1 and step 2. As long as you cover the range `t\in[1, NDATA]` and `NCOEFFS <= NDATA`, the choice of breakpoints is arbitrarily. I believe that if you choose the breakpoints to be `{1, 3, ..., NDATA-2, NDATA }` the fit will goes through the data points (notice that I skipped the internal points `t=2` and `t=NDATA-1` such that `NBREAK=NDATA-2` and `NCOEFFS=NDATA`). That is how [NAG](http://www.nag.com/numeric/CL/nagdoc_cl24/html/E01/e01bac.html) library selects the breakpoints to get an interpolation fit (meaning: a fit that pass trough the data points).

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer Vinicius. It's probably going to take me a day or two to digest that and really understand it. It's clear to me that I need to do much more learning in regards to the fundamentals of splines.

Comment: If you read carefully the example in GSL documentation, then you will see that the practical implementation of 1D non-parametric b-spline fit is not very complicated. Follow that to get f_1(t) and f_2(t) fits.